# Rotate an object in direction of motion in openGL

Tags: visual-c++, opengl

I'm working on an openGL assignment where I have an animal moving across the terrain on a random walk.  I need him to face in the direction of motion, but my trig is sub-par.  I thought I could do that by doing

```
glRotatef(atan2(dx, dy) * 180 / 3.14, 0, 0, 1);
```

but that rarely works out correctly.  What am I missing?

Comment: It depends on the axis of rotation. Always keep the axis of rotation pass through the center of object. First rotate it then only translate.

Comment: I did do that.  He just never faces the right way when he's moving

Comment: Looks good to me. Exactly what is wrong with the output you're getting?

Comment: When they are walking, they face some random direction that isn't necessarily the direction of motion.  Occasionally they line up but not often

Comment: I should point out that they are rotating on the correct axis, but just not the right angle

Answer (score 1):

No wonder it didn't work.  I got the dx and dy backwards on my program and accidentally typed them right here.  Thank you everyone for looking at it